# Why Can't I Get My Web Page to Jump To The Requested Page Thru VBA Excel

Tags: excel, web, vba

I am trying to get VBA Excel to navigate thru the data table on a web page.
The web page opens at page # 1.  I can update the web page number with VBA Excel code.  (At least it looks like its working.)
But I can not seem to get the data which applies to my requested page to display on the screen.  If I click on the drop down page button with my mouse, the button seems "dead".  I can select another page successfully with the mouse OK and then I can select the page number which I tried to pick with Excel VBA OK also.
I am using IE. Version 11 which I believe uses the dispatch event.
I have been trying all sorts of tricks which I researched on the net without success.
The following code is my latest attempt.  I hope someone with more experience than me can help.  Thanks in advance.

```
Sub ExtractTablesData()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim obj As Object
    Dim elemCollection As Object
    Dim evt

    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With IE
      .Visible = True
      .navigate ("http://My Web Page")

      While IE.readystate <> 4               ' wait for pages to download
        DoEvents
      Wend

      Do While IE.busy: DoEvents: Loop       ' make sure page has downloaded
      Set elemCollection = IE.Document.getelementsbytagname("TABLE")

      Set evt = IE.Document.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
      evt.initEvent "change", False, True

      IE.Document.getElementsbyClassName("pager-select")(0).selectedIndex = 5 
                                    ' trying to get the 6th page of data

      IE.Document.getElementsbyClassName("pager-select")(0).Click
      IE.Document.getElementsbyClassName("pager-select")(0).dispatchEvent (evt)

      Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:02"))

      Do While IE.busy: DoEvents: Loop    ' make sure page has downloaded  

      While IE.readystate <> 4            ' wait for pages to download
        DoEvents
      Wend

    End With   ' IE
```

Answer (score 0):

Had True False reversed.
Accidentally found correct answer on another webpage.
Works like a charm now.

evt.initEvent "change", True, False